# Double wells and triple wells quantum oscillators

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, oscillatory-integral

The Hamiltonion for the double well and triple wells can be written in form $H=H_0-x^2+x^4$ and $H=H_0+x^2-x^4+x^6$, repectively. Can anyboody guide which "basis function" can be used to construct the corresponding matrix elements for double and triple wells (which full-fills the BC's).? Please also tell me which method can be used to calculate the matrix elemnents,which may includes number of Gaussian integrals to solve.(Waiting for yours suggestion).+

Comment: Side note: your "triple well" potential doesn't look like a triple well: https://www.google.ru/search?q=plot+x%5E2-x%5E4%2Bx%5E6&oq=plot+x%5E2-x%5E4%2Bx%5E6&aqs=chrome..69i57.4280j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: However, a slight variation on it does: $x^2-2x^4+x^6$ https://www.google.ru/search?num=20&newwindow=1&ei=DbU7WreBK-bcgAavwrDwAg&q=plot+x%5E6-2x%5E4%2Bx%5E2&oq=plot+x%5E6-2x%5E4%2Bx%5E2&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3772.3772.0.4034.1.1.0.0.0.0.68.68.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.UJYO2w3bIVs

Comment: Ivan Neretin :You are right, it needs a little modifications as you mentioned.

Comment: [... in contrast to
the harmonic oscillator, the anharmonic oscillator cannot
be solved analytically](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0603165). This is with a $+x^2$ term but I'm pretty sure there are not analytic solutions in your case. There are [many approximation schemes](https://www.google.ca/search?q=quartic+oscillator+wave+function+analytic&client=ubuntu&ei=C1k9WvGUOs_cjwOx6aboCQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=1206&bih=677).